# C# Singleplayer Blackjack Game

Tags: c#, playing-cards

I recently finished a simple Blackjack game that I made to get better at C#. I am wondering how I can better organize or simplify my code. There are 4 files:

#### Program.cs

```
/*  Blackjack Game Copyright (C) 2018

This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program. If not, see<https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>. */

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

using Blackjack;

namespace Blackjack
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static Deck deck = new Deck();
        private static Player player = new Player();


        private enum RoundResult
        {
            PUSH,
            PLAYER_WIN,
            PLAYER_BUST,
            PLAYER_BLACKJACK,
            DEALER_WIN,
            SURRENDER,
            INVALID_BET
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize Deck, deal the player and dealer hands, and display them.
        /// </summary>
        static void InitializeHands()
        {
            deck.Initialize();

            player.Hand = deck.DealHand();
            Dealer.HiddenCards = deck.DealHand();
            Dealer.RevealedCards = new List<Card>();

            // If hand contains two aces, make one Hard.
            if (player.Hand[0].Face == Face.Ace && player.Hand[1].Face == Face.Ace)
            {
                player.Hand[1].Value = 1;
            }

            if (Dealer.HiddenCards[0].Face == Face.Ace && Dealer.HiddenCards[1].Face == Face.Ace)
            {
                Dealer.HiddenCards[1].Value = 1;
            }

            Dealer.RevealCard();

            player.WriteHand();
            Dealer.WriteHand();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles everything for the round.
        /// </summary>
        static void StartRound()
        {
            Console.Clear();

            if (!TakeBet())
            {
                EndRound(RoundResult.INVALID_BET);
                return;
            }
            Console.Clear();

            InitializeHands();
            TakeActions();

            Dealer.RevealCard();

            Console.Clear();
            player.WriteHand();
            Dealer.WriteHand();

            player.HandsCompleted++;

            if (player.Hand.Count == 0)
            {
                EndRound(RoundResult.SURRENDER);
                return;
            }
            else if (player.GetHandValue() > 21)
            {
                EndRound(RoundResult.PLAYER_BUST);
                return;
            }

            while (Dealer.GetHandValue() <= 16)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Dealer.RevealedCards.Add(deck.DrawCard());

                Console.Clear();
                player.WriteHand();
                Dealer.WriteHand();
            }


            if (player.GetHandValue() > Dealer.GetHandValue())
            {
                player.Wins++;
                if (Casino.IsHandBlackjack(player.Hand))
                {
                    EndRound(RoundResult.PLAYER_BLACKJACK);
                }
                else
                {
                    EndRound(RoundResult.PLAYER_WIN);
                }
            }
            else if (Dealer.GetHandValue() > 21)
            {
                player.Wins++;
                EndRound(RoundResult.PLAYER_WIN);
            }
            else if (Dealer.GetHandValue() > player.GetHandValue())
            {
                EndRound(RoundResult.DEALER_WIN);
            }
            else
            {
                EndRound(RoundResult.PUSH);
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ask user for action and perform that action until they stand, double, or bust.
        /// </summary>
        static void TakeActions()
        {
            string action;
            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                player.WriteHand();
                Dealer.WriteHand();

                Console.Write("Enter Action (? for help): ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                action = Console.ReadLine();
                Casino.ResetColor();

                switch (action.ToUpper())
                {
                    case "HIT":
                        player.Hand.Add(deck.DrawCard());
                        break;
                    case "STAND":
                        break;
                    case "SURRENDER":
                        player.Hand.Clear();
                        break;
                    case "DOUBLE":
                        if (player.Chips <= player.Bet)
                        {
                            player.AddBet(player.Chips);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            player.AddBet(player.Bet);
                        }
                        player.Hand.Add(deck.DrawCard());
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Valid Moves:");
                        Console.WriteLine("Hit, Stand, Surrender, Double");
                        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        break;
                }

                if (player.GetHandValue() > 21)
                {
                    foreach (Card card in player.Hand)
                    {
                        if (card.Value == 11) // Only a soft ace can have a value of 11
                        {
                            card.Value = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } while (!action.ToUpper().Equals("STAND") && !action.ToUpper().Equals("DOUBLE")
                && !action.ToUpper().Equals("SURRENDER") && player.GetHandValue() <= 21);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Take player's bet
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Was the bet valid</returns>
        static bool TakeBet()
        {
            Console.Write("Current Chip Count: ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine(player.Chips);
            Casino.ResetColor();

            Console.Write("Minimum Bet: ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(Casino.MinimumBet);
            Casino.ResetColor();

            Console.Write("Enter bet to begin hand " + player.HandsCompleted + ": ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            string s = Console.ReadLine();
            Casino.ResetColor();

            if (Int32.TryParse(s, out int bet) && bet >= Casino.MinimumBet && player.Chips >= bet)
            {
                player.AddBet(bet);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Perform action based on result of round and start next round.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="result">The result of the round</param>
        static void EndRound(RoundResult result)
        {
            switch (result)
            {
                case RoundResult.PUSH:
                    player.ReturnBet();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    Console.WriteLine("Player and Dealer Push.");
                    break;
                case RoundResult.PLAYER_WIN:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    Console.WriteLine("Player Wins " + player.WinBet(false) + " chips");
                    break;
                case RoundResult.PLAYER_BUST:
                    player.ClearBet();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Player Busts");
                    break;
                case RoundResult.PLAYER_BLACKJACK:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    Console.WriteLine("Player Wins " + player.WinBet(true) + " chips with Blackjack.");
                    break;
                case RoundResult.DEALER_WIN:
                    player.ClearBet();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Dealer Wins.");
                    break;
                case RoundResult.SURRENDER:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Player Surrenders " + (player.Bet / 2) + " chips");
                    player.Chips += player.Bet / 2;
                    player.ClearBet();
                    break;
                case RoundResult.INVALID_BET:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Bet.");
                    break;
            }

            if (player.Chips <= 0)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("You ran out of Chips after " + (player.HandsCompleted - 1) + " rounds.");
                Console.WriteLine("500 Chips will be added and your statistics have been reset.");

                player = new Player();
            }

            Casino.ResetColor();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
            Console.ReadKey();
            StartRound();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Console cannot render unicode characters without this line
            Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            Casino.ResetColor();
            Console.Title = "♠♥♣♦ Blackjack";

            Console.WriteLine("♠♥♣♦ Welcome to Blackjack v" + Casino.GetVersionCode());
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to play.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            StartRound();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Casino.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Blackjack
{
    public class Casino
    {
        private static string versionCode = "1.0";

        public static int MinimumBet { get; } = 10;
        public static string GetVersionCode() { return versionCode; }

        /// <param name="hand">The hand to check</param>
        /// <returns>Returns true if the hand is blackjack</returns>
        public static bool IsHandBlackjack(List<Card> hand)
        {
            if (hand.Count == 2)
            {
                if (hand[0].Face == Face.Ace && hand[1].Value == 10) return true;
                else if (hand[1].Face == Face.Ace && hand[0].Value == 10) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reset Console Colors to DarkGray on Black
        /// </summary>
        public static void ResetColor()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        }
    }

    public class Player
    {
        public int Chips { get; set; } = 500;
        public int Bet { get; set; }
        public int Wins { get; set; }
        public int HandsCompleted { get; set; } = 1;

        public List<Card> Hand { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add Player's chips to their bet.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bet">The number of Chips to bet</param>
        public void AddBet(int bet)
        {
            Bet += bet;
            Chips -= bet;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set Bet to 0
        /// </summary>
        public void ClearBet()
        {
            Bet = 0;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cancel player's bet. They will neither lose nor gain any chips.
        /// </summary>
        public void ReturnBet()
        {
            Chips += Bet;
            ClearBet();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Give player chips that they won from their bet.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="blackjack">If player won with blackjack, player wins 1.5 times their bet</param>
        public int WinBet(bool blackjack)
        {
            int chipsWon;
            if (blackjack)
            {
                chipsWon = (int) Math.Floor(Bet * 1.5);
            }
            else
            {
                chipsWon = Bet * 2;
            }

            Chips += chipsWon;
            ClearBet();
            return chipsWon;
        }

        /// <returns>
        /// Value of all cards in Hand
        /// </returns>
        public int GetHandValue()
        {
            int value = 0;
            foreach(Card card in Hand)
            {
                value += card.Value;
            }
            return value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Write player's hand to console.
        /// </summary>
        public void WriteHand()
        {
            // Write Bet, Chip, Win, Amount with color, and write Round #
            Console.Write("Bet: ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            Console.Write(Bet + "  ");
            Casino.ResetColor();
            Console.Write("Chips: ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.Write(Chips + "  ");
            Casino.ResetColor();
            Console.Write("Wins: ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine(Wins);
            Casino.ResetColor();
            Console.WriteLine("Round #" + HandsCompleted);

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Your Hand (" + GetHandValue() + "):");
            foreach (Card card in Hand) {
                card.WriteDescription();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public class Dealer
    {
        public static List<Card> HiddenCards { get; set; } = new List<Card>();
        public static List<Card> RevealedCards { get; set; } = new List<Card>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Take the top card from HiddenCards, remove it, and add it to RevealedCards.
        /// </summary> 
        public static void RevealCard()
        {
            RevealedCards.Add(HiddenCards[0]);
            HiddenCards.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        /// <returns>
        /// Value of all cards in RevealedCards
        /// </returns>
        public static int GetHandValue()
        {
            int value = 0;
            foreach (Card card in RevealedCards)
            {
                value += card.Value;
            }
            return value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Write Dealer's RevealedCards to Console.
        /// </summary>
        public static void WriteHand()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dealer's Hand (" + GetHandValue() + "):");
            foreach (Card card in RevealedCards)
            {
                card.WriteDescription();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < HiddenCards.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                Console.WriteLine("<hidden>");
                Casino.ResetColor();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Deck.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Blackjack
{
    public class Deck
    {
        private List<Card> cards;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initilize on creation of Deck.
        /// </summary>
        public Deck()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        /// <returns>
        /// Returns a Cold Deck-- a deck organized by Suit and Face.
        /// </returns>
        public List<Card> GetColdDeck()
        {
            List<Card> coldDeck = new List<Card>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    coldDeck.Add(new Card((Suit)j, (Face)i));
                }
            }

            return coldDeck;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Remove top 2 cards of Deck and turn it into a list.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>List of 2 Cards</returns>
        public List<Card> DealHand()
        {
            // Create a temporary list of cards and give it the top two cards of the deck.
            List<Card> hand = new List<Card>();
            hand.Add(cards[0]);
            hand.Add(cards[1]);

            // Remove the cards added to the hand.
            cards.RemoveRange(0, 2);

            return hand;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Pick top card and remove it from the deck
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The top card of the deck</returns>
        public Card DrawCard()
        {
            Card card = cards[0];
            cards.Remove(card);

            return card;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Randomize the order of the cards in the Deck.
        /// </summary>
        public void Shuffle()
        {
            Random rng = new Random();

            int n = cards.Count;
            while(n > 1)
            {
                n--;
                int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
                Card card = cards[k];
                cards[k] = cards[n];
                cards[n] = card;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Replace the deck with a Cold Deck and then Shuffle it.
        /// </summary>
        public void Initialize()
        {
            cards = GetColdDeck();
            Shuffle();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Card.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using static Blackjack.Suit;
using static Blackjack.Face;

namespace Blackjack
{
    public enum Suit
    {
        Clubs,
        Spades,
        Diamonds,
        Hearts
    }
    public enum Face
    {
        Ace,
        Two,
        Three,
        Four,
        Five,
        Six,
        Seven,
        Eight,
        Nine,
        Ten,
        Jack,
        Queen,
        King
    }

    public class Card
    {
        public Suit Suit { get; }
        public Face Face { get; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public char Symbol { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initilize Value and Suit Symbol
        /// </summary> 
        public Card(Suit suit, Face face)
        {
            Suit = suit;
            Face = face;

            switch (Suit)
            {
                case Clubs:
                    Symbol = '♣';
                    break;
                case Spades:
                    Symbol = '♠';
                    break;
                case Diamonds:
                    Symbol = '♦';
                    break;
                case Hearts:
                    Symbol = '♥';
                    break;
            }
            switch (Face)
            {
                case Ten:
                case Jack:
                case Queen:
                case King:
                    Value = 10;
                    break;
                case Ace:
                    Value = 11;
                    break;
                default:
                    Value = (int)Face + 1;
                    break;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Print out the description of the card, marking Aces as Soft or Hard.
        /// </summary>
        public void WriteDescription()
        {
            if (Suit == Suit.Diamonds || Suit == Suit.Hearts)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            }

            if (Face == Ace)
            {
                if (Value == 11)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Symbol + " Soft " + Face + " of " + Suit);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Symbol + " Hard " + Face + " of " + Suit);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Symbol + " " + Face + " of " + Suit);
            }
            Casino.ResetColor();
        }
    }
}
```

> **Program.cs:** This file controls the game by printing most text and taking > player input.
>
> **Casino.cs:** This file contains "the rules of the house" as well as Player and > Dealer classes.
>
> **Deck.cs:** This file contains the code for the Deck--drawing cards and 
>   shuffling.
>
> **Card.cs:** This file contains the code for the Card class.

Comment: You should create rng only once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things I noticed:

Instead of adding one to the `Face` enum value, it would make sense to me to make `Ace = 1,`.  This will automatically set all the rest to where you need them.

A `Hand` class would make sense.  This could handle the sum of the cards as well keep track of which is hidden and which is revealed.  This removes some redundancy between the player's hand and the dealers hand

I would suggest taking the decision of hard or soft sum away from `Card` and put it in `Hand`.  The value of the Ace will be hard or soft depending on the other cards in the hand.

A `Game` to handle the play of the game would improve your design, as well as reduce the refactoring that would be needed to extend this to a GUI version.

I noticed you're printing various messages out in different colors.  A separate `Message` class with properties to control the attributes of each message, would help.  The messages could then be stored in a `Dictionary<String,Message>`

Instead of hard coding Console printing, change your methods to accept streams and pass those as arguments in the constructor of the game.  Now you can interface with a console, network , or GUI.

Comment: Thank you for these answers. What do you mean by storing messages in a Dictionary as <String, Message>? Would would each represent?

Comment: @Orion31 -  A`Message` class could contain a `string` with the actual message and any format options used to display the message(i.e. color, bold, underline, etc.).  A string would be used to identify the message.  I didn't realize at the time that you had an `enum` for that.  A `Dictionary<RoundResult,Message>` would make more sense.

Answer (score -1):

Reffering to the line:
chipsWon = (int) Math.Floor(Bet * 1.5);

BlackJack indeed pays 1.5 time but in your code you deducted the bet so the return should be 2.5 time

Comment: At least in Las Vegas you are wrong https://lasvegassun.com/news/2017/may/05/5-tips-to-beat-blackjack-in-vegas-from-a-gamblers.